# error: not found: value :::

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, pattern-matching

I can create a list like so:

```
val value = List(1) ::: 2 :: List(3)
```

Now I am trying to decompose that list like so:

```
value match { case a ::: b :: c => (a, b, c) }
```

but I get `error: not found: value :::`.

Why I am getting this error. Why doesn't this pattern work, and what should I use instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have

```
val xs = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

and suppose there is an extractor object that could extract a collection prefix. What should be matched for

```
case a ::: b :: c => (a, b, c)
```

Is it (choose all that apply)

- `(List(1, 2, 3), 4, Nil)`
- `(List(1, 2), 3, List(4))`
- `(List(1), 2 , List(3, 4))`
- `(Nil, 1, List(2, 3, 4))`

Because there is more than one way of matching the pattern, the above extractor cannot exist. Instead you could use the following.

```
value match { case a :: b :: c => (List(a), b, c) }
```

Comment: just to add you can also match this way if you know exact list size (3 elems): `value match { case List(a, b, c) => (a, b, c) }`